# HighCharts: Line series disappears on click of legend

Tags: highcharts

I've created the chart with Column and Line series, where I'm  adding the series dynamically using the chart.addSeries.

Issue:
When clicking the line series legend, the line series disappears. when clicking it for the second time only the plot points are visible and line is not visible.

I'm getting following JS exception:

Line: 65
Character: 237
Code: 0
Error Message: Object doesn't support property or method 'join'
URL: http://pfmonline.fidelitypfm.com:8098/moneycenter/js/js/rbc/highcharts.js?d=1592588911

Below is the code:

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'spendingChart',
            width: spendingChart.width*0.8,
            height: spendingChart.height*0.8,
            plotBorderColor:'#000000',
            plotBorderWidth:1
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: subCategories,
            labels: {
                rotation: 0
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            borderColor: '#000',
            backgroundColor: '#FFF',
            borderRadius: 0,
            borderWidth: 1,
            formatter: function() {
                var s;
                s = ''+this.series.name+', '+this.x  +', $'+Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2,'.',',');
                return s;
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        yAxis: {
            lineWidth: 1,
            title: {
                text: ''
            }
        },

        series: []
    });
    for(var i=0;i<data[index].drilldown.length;i++){
        if(data[index].drilldown[i].name == "Actual")
            chtType = "column";
        else
            chtType = "spline";
        subCategories = [];
        versionsData = [];
        var color = "";
        for (var j = 0; j < data[index].drilldown[i].data.length; j++) {
            versionsData.push(data[index].drilldown[i].data[j].y);
            subCategories.push(data[index].drilldown[i].categories[j]);
            color  = (data[index].drilldown[i].data[j].color);
        }
        chart.xAxis[0].setCategories(subCategories, false);
        chart.addSeries({type:chtType, name :data[index].drilldown[i].name, data : versionsData ,color:color},'true');
    }
```

Comment: Any live example would be possible? Also, sample of not working data would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with the lines disappearing when clicking the legend and found the solution, apparently it was a bug involving the 2.2.5 version and jQuery 1.8. They have fixed it so if you upgrade to the latest 2.3.5 it will be fixed.

Reference: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1189 and https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1181

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your inputs I'll try with this version.

Comment: Has this fixed your problem?

Comment: This fixed my problem. YAY!

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using IE.

Since you are with arrays, check for any trailing **commas**.

If your IE version is **< 8**. Check for the IE mode. If your in quirks mode.

```
var test = [
["element1"],
["element2"],
["element3"],
["element4"],
["element5"],
];
```

Remove the trailing **`,`**.

Alternatively, you can check either by logging or alerting the **`length`**.

```
console.log(test.length);
```

or

```
alert(test.length);
```

The length you will observe will be 6 instead of 5.